# Is there a word for the back and forth movement of the waters on a beach?

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried to look it up around on reserve dictionaries and via google, but couldn't quite find a word that fitted what I meant to say. Essentially, is there a word that encompasses both the actions of the water approaching the bank and receding from it ?

Sample sentence:

> It wouldn't be a constant pool to pull from, rather a [insert desired word here].

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence where you'd use the word? It's currently not clear if you're talking about tides or waves.

Comment: Do you mean the tides? Ebb and flow?

Comment: Ah yes, that it was I meant!
And as for a sentence example: "it wouldn't be a constant pool to pull from, rather a [insert desired word here]"

Comment: @SConroy please post "ebb and flow" as the answer, don't forget to say "why". It seems the OP is satisfied with that solution, let's hope they return and accept the answer!

Comment: @Mari-Lou. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the tides -- the [ebb and flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebb_and_flow)?

Wikipedia

> Ebb and flow (also called ebb and flood and flood drain) are two
>   phases of the tide or any similar movement of water. The ebb is the
>   outgoing phase, when the tide drains away from the shore; and the flow
>   is the incoming phase when water rises again. The terms are also
>   common in figurative use.

Answer (score 1):

The "lapping" of the water may work, however, I am not certain this fits your exact usage as I don't think this applies solely to beaches.

Answer (score 1):

**wave-action**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226383?redirectedFrom=wave%20action#eid15086674)

> n.  (a) Geology the action of water flowing in waves

As in:

> **Wave Action** is important for building up and breaking down shorelines.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are describing a reservoir of water which is regularly refilled. 
Either:

> "it wouldn't be a constant **source** to pull from, rather a [**tidal
>   pool**]"

Or

> "it wouldn't be a constant pool to **draw** from, rather a [**tidal
>   source**]"

('draw,' as in 'draw water from' is only for variation and euphony)

Answer (score 1):

**[tide](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tide)** (Collins)

> 2. countable noun
>      A **tide** is a current in the sea that is caused by the regular and continuous movement of large areas of water **towards and away from the shore**.
>      *Roman vessels used to sail with the tide from Boulogne to Richborough.*

(**towards and away from the shore** emphasis mine.)